# Scroll is not working if "this.props.navigator.push" is used?

Tags: react-native, navigator

If i use `navigator.push`, scroll is not working in that particular page and scroll is working if i used `navigator.replace` but unable to go back to the previous page.

Code below:

```
 this.props.navigator.push({
    title: 'Terms & Conditions',
    id:'Terms',
 });
```

Kindly tell me how to overcome this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRY with this

```
var tmp=this.props.navigator.getCurrentRoutes();
this.props.navigator.immediatelyResetRouteStack([tmp[0],{title:'Terms & Conditions',  id:'Terms', address: selectedShipAdd}]);
```